# Join multiple SQL tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, join

I'm stuck trying to join multiple tables together. I have a user table with the users' names and three other tables for patients, doctors, and appointments. The appointment table has the patient's and doctor's id. I can only join two tables, for example, the appointments and the patient, to show the patients' data like the following.

```
$data = User::join('appointments','users.id','=','appointments.user_id')
```

I want to know how to do this for the patient and doctor simultaneously. The users' table in DB has a name, last name, phone number, and role id(1 for doctor, 3 for patient). The appointment table has user_id, doctor_id, date, and time. I want to get the user name and the doctor's name.

Comment: You should read about Eloquent relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
Example:

```
$user = DB::table('user')
        ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->where('posts.title', 'Example')
        ->get();
```

[Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return $user = User::leftJoin('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('orders','orders.user_id',  '=', 'users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('appointments','appointments.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->get();
```

[Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of the ways mentioned. You could also do a relationship between the models. Then when you call the User model just use

```
->with('orders')->with('appointments')->get();
```

Through eloquent magic all the orders and all the appointments for that user will be added to the relationship on your collection. Look up one to many relationships in the Laravel docs.